# Help proving that $\lim(s_n+t_n)=+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $\lim s_n=+\infty$ and if $(t_n)$ is a bounded sequence, then $\lim(s_n+t_n)=+\infty$.

**My proof:**

Suppose $\lim s_n=+\infty$ and $(t_n)$ is bounded.

Since $\lim s_n=+\infty$, by definition we have that for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $s_n>M$.

Since $(t_n)$ is bounded, we have that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $k\leq t_n\leq k'$ for some $k,k'\in\mathbb{R}$.

This is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to put these two definitions together coherently. It's obvious to me that $t_n$ being bounded means that $s_n + t_n >M$. However, I'm having trouble arriving at this result from the definitions that I've stated.

Maybe since $\lim s_n=+\infty$, I could say that $s_n>M-t_n$ which implies that $s_n+t_n>M$. But I'm not sure how the definition of $t_n$ being bounded plays into this.

---

Am I on the right track? Any hints/advice would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I think you gave the definition of $s_n$ correctly.  Maybe since $s_n$ is unbounded, we have that at some point $P$, $s_n>t_n$. Then concluding that $s_n+t_n$>$M$?

Comment: Try working with a constant with regards to the bounded sequence. More specifically, show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [s_n + k]$ diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to prove that $\lim (s_n + t_n) = \infty$.

Given some $A \in \mathbb{R}$.

We know that there exists $K$ such that $|t_n| < K$ for all $n$.

Since $\lim s_n = \infty$, we can pick $N$ such that $n\ge N\implies s_n \ge A+K$.

Thus, $n\ge N \implies s_n+t_n\ge A \ \ \blacksquare$.

Comment: I used to struggle with these proofs as well. Make sure to think about what exactly you want to prove. I always start these proofs with "given some $A$ / given some $\epsilon$ (as appropriate)". Consider the definition of the statement as a "challenge": if an adversary **gives** you some $A$, how do you come up with $N$ that beats the challenge?

Further comment on your attempt:

The way you did it almost worked (you got $s_n>M-t_n$). You just have to see that $|t_n|<K$.

Comment: Ok, cool I think this is exactly what I was looking for. An equivalent way of saying that $t_n$ is bounded is that $|t_n|<K$?

Comment: Well, you should say "there exists K such that...".

Comment: haha ya I know. I guess I was just blanking on the fact that since its bounded, obviously there exists a $K$ such that $-K<t_n<K$, which is to say that $|t_n|<K$. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: "$(t_n)$ is bounded" is equivalent to, "There exists K such that $|t_n|<K$  for all $n$". And +1 for this answer: I would have written the proof in the exact same way.

Comment: In terms of the variables in the original question, it's sufficient to choose $N$ such that whenever $n \ge N$, then $s_n \ge A - k$ (with the thought in the back of one's mind that $k$ might be a "very negative" number, but the boundedness of $t_n$ still ensures that $k$ remains "finitely negative").

Comment: Wow... 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes. I’ve never had such a controversial answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can do a proof by “ contradiction “. Assume $s_n + t_n \to L < \infty $, then $s_n + t_n$ is bounded, say by $M$. Thus $|s_n| = |s_n + t_n - t_n| \le |s_n + t_n| + |t_n| \le M + T$. So $s_n$ is bounded, but it is unbounded since $s_n \to \infty $. Therefore $s_n + t_n \to \infty $.

Comment: And what about the case where $s_n + t_n$ does not approach infinity, but not because it has a finite limit?  (For example, to rule out the possibility that $s_n + t_n = (-1)^n n$.  Or the possibility that $s_n + t_n = (-1)^n$.)

Comment: @Daniel Schepler: I thought about the case you brought up but assumed OP’s sequence is either convergent to $\infty$ or to $L < \infty $.